# Django django-custom-user and registration becomes no-op

Tags: django, django-templates

#### Registration fails silently with django-custom-user

I'm switching from using the default registration model to a custom model (to drop username and just authenticate with email address).  An existing user can login, but creating a new user fails silently now.  I call `url 'registration_register'`, I get the user create form I expect, I fill it in and click the submit button, and...the form redisplays with email but not password, no error, no user creation.

#### registration_form.html

```
{% extends "..." %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'registration_register' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.email.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">mail</label> {{ form.email }}
<br>
{{ form.password1.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}">password</label> {{ form.password1 }}
<br>
{{ form.password2.errors }}
<label for="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}">password</label> {{ form.password2 }}
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Create" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

#### More background

I pip install django-custom-user and make the changes recommended [here](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user) -- adding to INSTALLED_APPS, db sync (in fact, it's a new project, so db delete and create), and the couple code changes to use it.  I've left 'registration' in INSTALLED_APPS.

```
Django (1.7.6)
django-custom-user (0.5)
```

My `urls.py` still points to `registration.backends.default.urls`.

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem you face is that `django-registration` expects a username as well as a password and an email address. As you can see in the source code of `django-registration`

https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/backends/default/views.py?at=default#cl-74

If I were you I would simply create a simple form and use a FormView from django. After, in order to match django-registration you could do more research and try to fit django-registration with django-custom-user.

It could be that you create a class that inherits django-custom-user, or that you change the form or anything like that. Otherwise you could even fork django-registration and update it according to django-custom-user and then use it for your project and make it available on github as django-registration-custom-user

Comment: Yes, this is about the size of it.  It seems that the only examples I have found are incomplete in ways like this.  I've filed this issue, with a (very ugly but maybe demonstrative) patch.  https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Also try displaying the form as `form.as_p` in order to get all fields and all errors displayed automatically. Forget about CSS for now.

Also what package is `registration.backends.default.urls` ?
Because it is not `django-custom-user`

I hope this helps

Comment: DB:  Yes, I even started with "rm db.sqlite3".  And django-custom-user doesn't provide a urls.py, so I'm using the default registration package's urls.py.

Comment: Well the problem you face is that `django-registration` expects a username as well as a password and an email address. As you can see in the source code of `django-registration`

[source code](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/backends/default/views.py?at=default#cl-74)